# Stochastic versus primordial gravitational waves

Tags: cosmology, terminology, gravitational-waves

I have read differences terms but I doubt if they are exactly the same in Cosmology:

1. Primordial gravitational waves (and their background).
2. Stochastic gravitational waves (and their background).

Are they really the same or is there any difference?

Furthermore, I have also read about the following GW types:

1. Cosmological gravitational waves.
2. Astrophysical gravitational waves.
3. Relic gravitational waves.
4. GW from density perturbations.

I presume, after reading the first answer, that primordial gravitational waves are the same than relic gravitational waves and they are the waves inducing the B-modes on the CMB. What is the true analogue of the CMB for the GW sector? Is the Stochastic or the primordial? Or maybe the relic GW? I believe the terminology is a bit confusing at this point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primordial gravitational waves refer to those generated during inflation. They have been red-shifted to undetectable levels by the exponential inflationary expansion. “Stochastic” gravitational waves are random mixtures of waves generated by a variety of sources, but in contrast to “primordial” waves, are generated *after* inflation. In the cosmological setting, a stochastic gravitational wave background can be generated by density inhogemeities during the process of preheating after inflation.

Comment: What about relic gravitational waves????? And cosmological vs. astrophysical gravitational waves? I will edit to clear it all...